# Condicional if no funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, select2

Estoy intentando atraves de un select, dependiendo la opcion seleccionada, cargarle a otro select las opciones hijos, por ej , provincias "Buenos Aires" > ciudades "Ciudades de Buenos Aires", realmente nose que estoy haciendo mal pero no pude lograrlo aun, esto es una prueba de lo que hice hasta el momento.

```
var ciudades_BuenosAires = ['Azul', 'Bahia Blanca', 'Carmen de Patagones', 'La Plata', 'Mar del Plata', 'Necochea', 'Olavarria', 'Pergamino', 'San Nicolas', 'Villa Gesel'];

var provincias_txt = jQuery('#select2-ubicacion_provincia-container').text();

if (provincias_txt == 'Buenos Aires') {
    jQuery(ciudades_BuenosAires).each(function(i) {
        jQuery('#ubicacion_ciudad').append('<option value=' + ciudades_BuenosAires[i] + '\>' + ciudades_BuenosAires[i] + '</option>');
    });
} else {
    alert('No es Buenos Aires')
}
```

Comment: De donde estas obteniendo este select #select2-ubicacion_provincia-container? son option fijos en el html?

Comment: En realidad #select2-ubicacion_provincia-container es el que almacena las opciones "padre" ej "Buenos Aires" y #ubicacion_ciudades es donde debo almacenar las opciones "hijo" ej "ciudades de Buenos Aires".

Comment: Si es un select con options fijos ejemplo <select><option value="Buenos Aires">Buenos Aires</option></select> debes usar el .val() en lugar del .text() al momento de hacer el selector JQuery

Comment: Si son option fijos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replique el código y usando el val() funciona correctamente, puedes ver los cambios a continuación, debes agregar un evento de change al select, para cuando cambien de opción sea ejecutado el código, según el valor seleccionado construirá el select hijo

```js
var ciudades_BuenosAires = ['Azul', 'Bahia Blanca', 'Carmen de Patagones', 'La Plata', 'Mar del Plata', 'Necochea', 'Olavarria', 'Pergamino', 'San Nicolas', 'Villa Gesel'];

    jQuery('#select2-ubicacion_provincia-container').on('change',function(){     
var provincias_txt = $(this).val();

if (provincias_txt == 'Buenos Aires') {
 jQuery(ciudades_BuenosAires).each(function(i) {
  jQuery('#ubicacion_ciudad').append('<option value=' + ciudades_BuenosAires[i] + '\>' + ciudades_BuenosAires[i] + '</option>');
 });
} else {
 $('#ubicacion_ciudad').empty()
 alert('No es Buenos Aires')
}
    })
```

```html
<script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      
    <select id="select2-ubicacion_provincia-container">
      <option value="Otra Opcion">Otra Opcion</option>
      <option value="Buenos Aires">Buenos Aires</option>
    </select>

    <select id="ubicacion_ciudad"></select>
```

Tu codigo esta bien, solo debes usar el val() en lugar del text() cuando vas a obtener atributos value de un elemento html.

Comment: Si, esto tiene sientido, probe y aun no se esta cumpliendo la condicion, ya que de entrada me aparece el alert y al seleccionar Buenos Aires no me carga la lista de opciones hijo, realmente nose porque

Comment: Entonces debes usar un evento, modifique el código para que veas el uso de los eventos en Jquery, te dejo la documentacion para que veas los diferentes eventos que puedes usar. [Documentacion](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/)

Comment: Gracias esto funciono!!!